# Getting error creating sdf offer in firefox v60.0.2 (WebRTC, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, webrtc

I'm getting next error when it fires RTCPeerConnection.createOffer():

**DOMException**
**code**: 11
**columnNumber**: 0
**data**: null
**filename**: ""
**lineNumber**: 0
**message**: "Cannot create offer when there are no valid transceivers."
**name**: "InvalidStateError"
**result**: 2152923147
**stack**: ""
**__proto__**: DOMExceptionPrototype { name: Getter, message: Getter, INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, … } index.js:176:3

The full snippet of code is next (the error is fired by the line: **pc.createOffer().then(...**):

```js
let pc = {};
let localStream = {};
const btnStart = document.querySelector("button[id='btnstart']");
let localVideoDisplay = document.getElementById('vOwn');

btnStart.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{

  pc = new RTCPeerConnection();
  pc.onicecandidate = (event)=>{
   console.log(event);
  }
  /*
   It captures local media
  */
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: 1, video: 1 }).then((stream)=>{
   localStream = stream;
   localVideoDisplay.srcObject = localStream;
  }).catch((err)=>{
     console.log(err);
  });
  /* 
   It creates sdpOffer 
  */
  pc.createOffer().then((rtcSession)=>{
   console.log(rtcSession);
  }).catch((error)=>{
   console.log(error);
  });
 });
```

```html
<button id="btnstart">Start</button>
<video id="vOwn" autoplay></video>
```

The code works flawlessly on Chrome (mobile and desktop) and Safari (mobile v11.3.1 and desktop v11.0.2) my question is next: Is this a firefox bug or Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `pc.createOffer()` before adding any streams or creating a datachannel.

This is typically not what you want. Try this:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: 1, video: 1 }).then((stream)=>{
    localStream = stream;
    localVideoDisplay.srcObject = localStream;
    stream.getTracks().forEach((t) => pc.addTrack(t, stream));
    return pc.createOffer()
})
.then((rtcSession)=>{
    console.log(rtcSession);
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```